# Is it possible to add binary dependency into a framework, and then distribute that framework as a binary dependency(Swift Package)?

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift-package-manager, xcframework, swift-package

I am trying to create two frameworks, framework1 and framework 2. framework 2 has dependency on framework1, and eventually framework 2 will be the final framework used by diff applications, also framework2(XCFramework2) will be distributed through swift package.

Is it possible to add framework1(XCFramework1)into framework2 project through SPM(binary dependency) or any other way?

I know how to do it for source code-based dependencies, Package 1 as a dependency in to Package 2 will work, but here both are frameworks.

I checked this blog, but not sure in my case same will be applicable.
https://www.fleksy.com/blog/how-the-fleksy-sdk-is-privately-distributed-using-the-swift-package-manager/